# How to change tor to run by a different user?

Tags: tor

I downloaded the Tor Browser and i downloaded the tor bundle but when i click on the tor browser i get this

/home/username/.tor-browser/data/tor is not owned by this user (username, 1000) but by root (0). perhaps you are running tor as the wrong user?

failed to parse/validate config: couldn't access/create private data directory "home/username/.tor-browser/data/tor"

When i double click on the "start-tor-browser" it only opens the file. so that is why i downloaded the browser. i'm not sure how to change the name to my username so i can use tor.

Answer (score 2):

Try to restore the ownership on the `/home/username/.tor-browser` folder:

```
chown -R username: /home/username/.tor-browser
```

I think this should solve the problem.

Comment: I got "not permitted" :/

Comment: Did you lauch that command with sudo ? Like :

sudo chown -R username: /home/username/.tor-browser

Comment: O.O i'm and idiot.. Yea i forgot to launch it with sudo. ok so i got it to work as far as i know but now when i launch TOR it asks for a password but when i type in my password it doesn't work :/

Comment: Oh never mind i got it :P Thank you for the help :D